# I have a visit visa for America. If I cross the border and go towards Canada as a refugee, will they allow entry to Canada or not?

Tags: refugees

I applied for a visit visa to America and gained it. If I go to the Canadian Border after arriving at America and seek refuge in Canada, will they grant it to me or not??

Comment: You should read (https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/news/2017/03/claiming_asylum_incanadawhathappens.html), especially the section headed "Third Safe Country".

Comment: At best you could *apply* for refugee status, but whether they grant it or not applies entirely on your personal circumstances.  Either way, this question belongs on [Expats.SE] not Travel.

Comment: Given in this case that you would likely be voluntarily departing the USA where you *could* have sought refugee status, the answer is that you will almost certainly be declined. "Refugee" and "shopping" do not go together. If you are in such fear for your life that you need refugee status, you can't, by definition, afford to tour various countries looking for a place to settle.

Comment: @RobertColumbia That's the theory to some extend, but it's not what is actually happening.

Answer (score 6):

The Canada-US Safe Third Country Agreement generally means that you must apply for refugee status in the first country (out of the US and Canada) that you arrive in. So since you arrived in the US, and you try to cross the border to Canada and apply for refugee status, this generally means they will turn you back.

However, this agreement only applies if you try to cross the border through a *legal* port of entry. If you cross through an *illegal* border crossing, e.g. Roxham Road, the agreement doesn't apply, and Canada will process your refugee application even though you arrived in the US first.

So many people cross at Roxham Road to take advantage of its illegal border crossing status that some taxi companies even drive people right to the end of that road so they can cross, and the Canadian government has built a makeshift refugee camp and reception center on the other side to handle the volume.

Comment: Since I'm not sure the OP understands this, it may be worth pointing out that they will be admitted as a refugee *claimant*, which does not mean that they will be granted refugee status.

Comment: Those taxi companies are basically acting as coyotes for illegal immigrants to Canada.

Comment: It's important to know how to speak the language there. Here are some phrases that might help: "Hi, please begin the prohcess for refugee status", "Sorey for crossing the border in the wrong place, eh."

Answer (score 1):

To enter Canada as a refugee, you must be referred. The United Nations Refugee Agency (UNHCR), a designated referral organization, or a private sponsorship group can refer you. You cannot apply directly as a refugee. https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/refugees/help-outside-canada.html

Comment: But if you enter Canada without referral, you can apply for asylum.